# putting a less wide div on a wider div

Tags: css, html, positioning

I am a novice in web developing. My container div is set to `margin: 0 auto; position: relative;` and it is displayed in the middle of the screen. I have a `banner` div within the container which has some background color which I want to extend the whole width of the screen. I decided to use another div outside the `container`div with same background color and height of my `banner` div and named it header. But how can I put them one over another, more precisely, the `container` div over the `header` div?

**EDIT:**
Some of the html:

```
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="banner">
      <img src="images/banner.gif" width="450" height="80" alt="parul library" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
#container{
position:relative;
top:0;
width: 968px;
background:#FFF;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
position:absolute;
top:0;
height: 80px;
background: rgb(222,239,255); /* Old browsers */

}
```

Comment: what position: does header div has?

Comment: Well, we're not playing 'guess the HTML,' could you show it to us? And your CSS. And, possibly, post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, live demo for us to play with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this CSS for the header div:

```
.header {
    background: #bada55;
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And make sure container has `position: relative;` in its style definition.

Here's a working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/rkJMJ/

**Update for the HTML and CSS posted in the question:**

(Added `width: 100;` to the #header style def)

```
#container{
position:relative;
top:0;
width: 968px;
background:#FFF;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
position:absolute;
top:0;
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
background: rgb(222,239,255); /* Old browsers */
}
```

Comment: thank you, the "width: 100%;" showed the trick. never thought that could solve it. thanks again.

Comment: Yes, absolutely positioned divs do not take up 100% width by default as their static positioned counterparts do.